# Date output to support all browsers javascript

Tags: javascript, date, browser-support

```
function getDateFromUrl(url)
{
var urlDateString = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/day/')+5);

urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("/index-1.html","");
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("th",""); 
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("rd",""); 
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("st",""); 
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace(","," "); 
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("/"," "); 
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("-"," ");
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("."," ");
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace(","," "); 
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("/"," "); 
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("-"," ");
urlDateString =urlDateString.replace("."," ");

return new Date(urlDateString);
}

function getDayFromDate(dt)
{

 switch (dt.getDay())
 {
 case 0:
   x="Sunday";
   break;
 case 1:
   x="Monday";
   break;
 case 2:
   x="Tuesday";
   break;
 case 3:
   x="Wednesday";
   break;
 case 4:
   x="Thursday";
   break;
 case 5:
   x="Friday";
   break;
 case 6:
   x="Saturday";
   break;
 }
return x;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FyEMD/

IE and opera do not support this script. in that they don't output the date whereas chrome and firefox do output the date. Would it be because they don't support date in string format. If so which format does the date have to be in.

input would look like C:\example\day\12-October-12 output should be date: Oct 12 2012 day: Friday The way the code is atm it works in chrome and firefox

Any help appreciated.

Comment: All I see here are two functions. Can you provide a sample input?  I assume you are calling the getDateFromUrl() function; what does your url look like?

Comment: input would look like C:\example\day\12-October-12
output should be date: Oct 12 2012 day: Friday 
The way the code is atm it works in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Ok, let's assume IE's developer tools still aren't up to par with the rest of the world; still, have you tried to trace the JS execution step by step in Opera's debugger?

Comment: Take a look at the date.js library.

Comment: Your JSfiddle does not work in Chrome (produces the labels `Date:` and `Day:` with nothing after them), and your example code produces the string `"xample\day\12 October 12"` in `urlDateString` for your example input data, which understandably won't be accepted by `Date` as a valid date value.

Comment: The script uses window.location.toString command to return the location being C:\example\day\12-October-12 (input) the code then takes out the C:\example\day\ and the 12 October 12 string is outputed in the html as new date. jsfiddle is just an example of the code used i can assure it is working in my html editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following formats for cross-browser `Date` construction:

```
"2010"

"2010-06"

"2010-06-09"

"2010-06-09T15:20:00Z"

"2010-06-09T15:20:00-07:00"

"2010/06/09"

"2009/6/9"

"2010/6/9 12:34"

"2010/6/9 12:34:56"

"June 9, 2010"

"2010 June 9"
```